# If $f$ is not identically zero and $|f(x)| \le 1$ for $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, then also $|g(x)| \le 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ satisfy the equation $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)g(y)$, $x$,$y$ $\in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that If $f$ is not identically zero and $|f(x)| \le 1$ for $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, then  also $|g(x)| \le 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is how I proceeded:

Putting $x=0$ in the functional equation We have $f(y)+f(-y)=2f(0)g(y)$. Taking modulus on both sides $|f(y)+f(-y)|=2|f(0)|g(y)|$ which gives $2|f(0)||g(y)|\le |f(y)|+|f(-y)|\le 2$

$\implies |f(0)||g(y)|\le 1,  \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$.

All I need to show is that $f(0) \ge 1$. Putting both $x=y=0$ in the functional equation we have $2f(0)=2f(0)g(0)\implies 2f(0)(1-g(0))=0.$

Now only putting $y=0$ in the equation we have $2f(x)(1-g(0))=0$. Since $f(x)$ is not identically $0$, $g(0)=1$. 
I am unable to show that $f(0) \ge 1$.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: $f(0)$ will never be greater than 1 because of your condition.

Comment: can it be exactly be $1$??

Comment: There is a simpler way to do the above. You have that, $2f(x)g(y) $ is bounded $ \forall x, y \in R$. This is true for non-zero x and in particular for the x where f attains its maximum. So,$ |g(y)| \leq M/M = 1$.

Comment: @Manasi yeah got it.. nice... thank you

Answer (score 5):

Let $M=\sup_{\Bbb{R}}|f(t)|$. Since $f$ is not identically zero we  conclude that $M>0$.

Consider $\epsilon\in(0,M)$. There is a real $x_\epsilon$ such that $|f(x_\epsilon)|>M-\epsilon$. Now, for a real $y\in\Bbb{R}$ we have
$$
2|g(y)|\cdot |f(x_\epsilon)|=|f(x_\epsilon+y)+f(x_\epsilon-y)|\leq
|f(x_\epsilon+y)|+|f(x_\epsilon-y)|\leq 2M
$$
Thus
$$
2(M-\epsilon)|g(y)|<2 |g(y)|\cdot |f(x_\epsilon)|\leq 2M
$$
or
$$
\forall\,y\in\Bbb{R},\quad|g(y)|\leq \frac{M}{M-\epsilon}
$$
But  $\epsilon\in(0,M)$ is arbitrary, letting $\epsilon$ tend to $0$, we conclude that
$|g(y)|\leq1$ for every $y\in\Bbb{R}$.$\qquad\square$

Comment: How do you conclude the last line while M/M-epsilon is greater than or equal to one? Sorry, i dont have math symbols on my cell phone...

Comment: @ Hamid, I do not understand you comment! $M/M=1$ isn't it ?

Comment: It is $\frac{M}{M-\epsilon}$

Comment: for a fixed $y$ you take the limit of $M/(M-\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon$ tend to $0^+$, you have the right to do that since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.